# How to collide .fbx animation in Unity

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am new to unity. I have two animation in .fbx format.They can move..Now i want when both will collide with each other a sound will produce.Is there any idea how i will do this.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to read about how Physics work, and then how Trigger-Events and Colission detection is handled.

Read [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Physics.html) here, and [this](http://www.unity3dstudent.com/2010/07/beginner-b01-basic-collision-detection/). The first one gives you insight on how the Unity engine works. The latter provides a video tutorial on how to do Collision Detection.

If you don't want to do that and just want the code, I found [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html) on a quick Google:

```
var crashSound : AudioClip; // set this to your sound in the inspector function   
OnCollisionEnter (collision : Collision) {    
    // next line requires an AudioSource component on this gameobject5.    
    audio.PlayOneShot(crashSound);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply..Actually i can apply physics on simple objects just like cube.But now i want to apply physics on animation which is my fbx file..I am not able to do this...I have added mesh collider,rigidbody gravity with my fbx file. I have a terrain which has terrain collider below it but when i press the play button my character will cross the terrain and fall down.. i don't know how what is this...I have already read all the links you have send...

Comment: I found this, maybe it's related? http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/47095/mesh-colliders-not-working-on-fbx-imported-buildin.html

Comment: You will have to uses a Collider, most common is the capsule as you can not animate colliders so mesh colliders will not work well on animated objects. you said you got a box to work, its the same concept.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a MeshCollider to the fbx meshes. Anyway, this is not a good idea because this will cause performance issues.

You can create an empty gameobject for each character, and add to them: the fbx animation and a simple collider (some cube, sphere, capsule, etc). Then, when you use a script for them, you attach it to the parent object and from there you handle the whole thing.

If you want that the collider moves from specific places from the animation (Like the punch movement, or a kick),then you can ask to your 3D animator/modeler to add a simple mesh on that points. For example, a sphere on one punch, which will move with the animation. Then, in Unity, you will hide the mesh of the sphere but add a mesh collider to it. :)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, if you apply an animation to an object then you'll loose the physics reaction. Don't trust me? See here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oINKQUJZc1Q

Obviously, animation are not part of Unity physics. Think about it... Unity physics decide position and rotation of objects accordingly to Newton and friends laws. How do you think these laws can accord to a keyframe arbitrary animation? They can't: hence the crazy results you get when you try.

How to solve it? Use Unity physics also for animation: learn to master [rigidbody.AddForce](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) and all the other stuff described [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html).

You may always want to keep the physics and the animation separated. [That's how you get out of trouble](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYT9RjS9Mqw).

If you really want to know: here's my personal experience on how to mediate physics with animation.

> Sometimes, even binding a simple parameter to the physics and another
>   to an animation (or a script which mediates user input) may result in
>   catastrophic results. I've made a starship: rotation controller by
>   user mouse (by flagging "block rigidbody rotation"), direction and
>   speed by physics. It was inside a box collider. Imagine what happens
>   if a cube, orientated by a few degrees angles, meets a flat ground: it
>   should fall and rotate until one of the faces lays completely on the
>   ground. This was impossible, as I blocked any physics interaction with
>   the rotation of the body: as a result the box wanted to get flat on
>   the ground but couldn't. This tension eventually made it move forward
>   forever: something impossible in real world. To mediate this error,
>   I've made the "block rotation" parameter change dynamically according
>   to the user input: as the ship is moving the rotation is controlled by
>   the user but as soon as the user stop controlling the ship the
>   rotation parameter is given back to the physics engine. Another
>   solution would be to cast a ray down the collider, check if the ground
>   is near and avoid collisions if the ship is not moving (this is how
>   the banshee in Halo Combat Evolved is controlled, I think). When
>   playing videogames, always have a look at how your user input is
>   mediated into the physics engine: you may discover things which a
>   normal player normally wouldn't notice.

Comment: btw, there could also be other causes to a non-working collider. This is just something to bear in mind when expecting your animated object to behave accordingly to physics.

Comment: Try [animatePhysics](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Animation-animatePhysics.html). I never had problems with animated characters if their velocity is not very high.